# Why does this INSERT not work?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql, insert

In the following block, RestaurantInt is a data type and update() opens a connection to the database and manipulates data.

```
public boolean registerRestaurant(RestaurantInt restaurant) {
    boolean result = update("INSERT INTO restaurants (name, emailAddress, houseNumber, postCode, password) VALUES (\'"+restaurant.getName()+"\', \'"+restaurant.getEmail()+"\', "+restaurant.getAddress().getHouseNumber()+", \'"+restaurant.getAddress().getPostCode()+"\', \'"+restaurant.getPassword()+"\')");
    return result;
}
```

Here's the structure of restaurants:

```
Name - Type - Null? - Extra
restaurantID - int(11) - NO - auto_increment (primary key)
name - varchar(20) - YES -
emailAddress - varchar(20) - NO -
houseNumber - int(11) - NO -    (multiple key)
postCode - varchar(6) - NO - 
password - varchar(20) - NO -
```

***EDIT***

I simply removed the escapes and it worked perfectly. I hadn't removed escapes because I had been instructed to always use escape. Throughout the rest of the project, it never posed an issue until now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You do not need to escape the single quotes because the strings are defined by double quotes. You should also put backticks around column names `name` and `password`. Please do some error checking. That will probably give you the answer, and if not, it will help us give you the answer.

Comment: Hope that the users of your app don't name the restaurant as "Yummy Burgers');drop table Restaurants ;--" http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: What an unhelpful edit, reverted. Please do not turn questions into nonsense. Accepting an answer marks the question resolved - you don't need to then vandalise the question (?).

Comment: Please don't deface your question. If you do this again, I will roll it back and lock the question from further editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming every variable you're inserting has a value (which even could not lead to an error), your mistake is probably related to escaping the single quotes in your SQL sentence. You don't have to do this, since they're included in a double-quotes sentence and they will be interpreted literally.

Comment: I don't think the backslashes would be the problem, but they just aren't necessary.

Comment: Not quite sure about this. Since the whole sentence is double-quoted, it will be treated literally, so the backslashes would be also inserted as they are (at least in theory).

Comment: No, they will still be escaped. They just don't need to be escaped :)

Comment: When exactly is it necessary to escape?

Comment: @Deeyennay for example, in this case: `update('INSERT INTO restaurants (name, emailAddress, houseNumber, postCode, password) VALUES (\'"+restaurant.getName()+"\', \'"+restaurant.getEmail()+"\', "+restaurant.getAddress().getHouseNumber()+", \'"+restaurant.getAddress().getPostCode()+"\', \'"+restaurant.getPassword()+"\')');` Note that the `update()` method is called with simple-quotes (`update('...')`), in this case, you would need to escape. If you use double-quotes, everything inside will be expanded and simple-quotes will remain this way.

Answer (score 0):

as you can read in one of the comments, you dont need to escape single quotes. 
BUT, your DB will probably escape them when running the insert. remove the escaping backslashes, this should work.
also consider using 
[PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)